# Intellij - Huge gutter?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-14

[image: Gutter]

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? The gutter is literally taking up 20% of the screen.

For context, I'm on a Surface Pro Book (3000x2000 resolution). The gutter seems "responsive" in that it shrinks if I create a split view. But it's incredibly annoying, especially when the gap is so huge.

Comment: Were you recently were using Full Screen or Distraction Free Mode? Try restarting IDE. Other than that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148002

Comment: Seems that you're in a Distraction free mode. Check menu View - Exit distraction free mode.